# Resource not found exception In Android 5.0.1

Tags: android, camera, drawable, android-5.0-lollipop

I Am working on camera, when I launch the application, activity will be visible for the user and I have a button to call camera intent. I have all my images used in activity in drawable-xxhdpi folder, This will work fine and now I will click the button to capture image and click on save the application crashes by giving **Resource not found exception**

Then I copied images from drawable-xxhdpi folder to drawable folder, The application works fine, Can anyone tell me the reason why First time Images are taking from drawable-xxhdpi folder and not the second time (After clicking save in camera).

This issue is only coming in Android 5.0.1, and works fine in Android 4.4.2

Any help will be appreciated

```
mainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_fragment_layout_with_header, null);
headerLayout = (RelativeLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.header);
headerLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_handheld_header_bg);
```

crash log

```
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02018f
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2345)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1850)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:408)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:17212)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at com.android.cc.android.fragments.BaseFragment.processHeader(BaseFragment.java:147)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at com.android.cc.android.fragments.BaseFragment.getViewApplyingHeaderConfiguration(BaseFragment.java:127)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at com.android.cc.android.fragments.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.java:103)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at com.android.cc.android.fragments.ContentFragment.onCreateView(ContentFragment.java:64)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at roboguice.activity.RoboFragmentActivity.onStart(RoboFragmentActivity.java:60)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at com.android.cc.android.activities.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:139)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at com.android.cc.android.activities.RootPotraiteActivity.onStart(RootPotraiteActivity.java:224)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1234)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6329)
05-19 11:54:44.194: E/AndroidRuntime(14497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
```

Comment: please put your code snip .

Answer (score 2):

However you solved your issue, this happen due to device size Your `Android4.4.2` device uses `drawable-xxhdpi` resource folder and your `Android 5.0.1` devices may be smaller in size it is searching images in `drawable-hdpi`  or other resource folder where images are not present so it troughs the exception `Resource not found`.

**Note:**

*Issue is not with android versions*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have 2 Galaxy s4 devices one with 4.4.2 and one with 5.0.1 and in 5.0.1 device, first time it is not showing when we come back from camera by clicking save, this issue occurs

Comment: because the application may be using `drawable-xxhdpi` resource folder after the  camara click

Comment: post your logcat file

Comment: I have added log file

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException`  and you solved that issue

Comment: If I add the images in drawable folder the crash will be resolved but I am trying to figure out why it is taking first time from xxhdpi and why not when coming back from camera

Comment: as i said  application may be using `drawable`  resource folder files after coming back from  camera

Comment: May be yes .. Thanks for Your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you put your images in `drawable-xxhdpi` and your are trying to run your application on Device or emulator which have xxhdpi  type device. then it will run. 
and if your are try to run same application in `ldpi` or `mdpi` type device then it will crash with `ResourceNotFoundException` just because of unavailability of your images in `drawable-ldpi , mdpi`,

**Punch line**

If you will put your images in just `drawable` folder then crash will not happen because android will take it for all device regardless from device configuration or type.

Comment: I agree your point, but my question is why it is taking first time why not coming back from camera?? any idea

Comment: in this line 'headerLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_handheld_header_bg); ' it is crashing

Comment: please let us know from where you are calling this line?

Comment: In oncreateview of my fragment.(After clicking save button in Camera then onActivityResult is not calling)